# Displaying flash messages on modal dialog box on submit rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

I am trying to build the modal box for registering emails addresses in rails.
I have done it but can not able to find the way to display the flash messages on modal dialog box when registration fails.
On submit the box gets closed and message is only getting display on home page. I do not have good knowledge of web or rails, but would be nice if I can get some pointers.

The functionality is working fine expect on fail, dialog box should display the messages on it instead of on home page. I know where is issue in my code but do not know approach to do it. Here is my code for dialog box

```
   <div id="register" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <%= form_for(@email, url: home_esave_path, :html => {class:"model-dialog"}) do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Register</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.text_field :email, class:"form-control",  placeholder: "Enter a valid gmail address" %>
            </div>
            <%= f.show_simple_captcha(:email=>"email", :label => "Human Authentication", :refresh_button_text => "Refresh text", class:"form-control", :placeholder => "Enter the code") %>
            <%= f.submit "Register me!",  :class => "btn register_button" %>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align:left">
            <!-- show in case of success -->
            <% if @email.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h2>
                <%= pluralize(@email.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
                this email from being saved:
              </h2>
              <ul>
                <% @email.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <% end %>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      </div>
```

my controller code to get the messages

```
def save
@email = Email.new(user_params)
if !user_params.nil?
  if @email.save_with_captcha
    flash[:success] = "Success! The email address #{@email.email} has been successfully registered. We will contact you as soon as we have available rooms for new beta testers."
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  else
    if @email.valid?
      flash[:error] = "The captcha is not correct, enter again the captcha."
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:error] = "You have put invalid #{@email.email}"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    end
  end
end
```

end
 Flash messages I am displaying outside this model which is obvious that will be displayed on home page. But I did not find way to display it on model dialog box.

here is how I am displaying the messages

```
  <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
      <div class="alert <%= alert_for(type) %> fade in">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
         <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        <%= message %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
```

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: I am not sure this can be done.  Flash is designed to appear when a new page is served.  I did this in one of my applications with a modal with Ajax and by essentially building/styling the flash message in my .js.erb view file.  I can post an answer explaining this approach a bit more if interested.

Comment: yes, if i can get approch it should be enough to git it work..even though I am not good in this language ..but atleast something to start thanks

Answer (score 0):

Flash is designed as a way to pass data between (controller) actions (see [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) for more information).  In your case, you specifically, do not want an action, so I don't think there is a way to do this.

You can however generate a message that looks like your other flash messages using Ajax.  Here is one way to do it.

You will need the following components:

**Remote call from modal**

Add `remote: true` or `:remote => true` to your form within the modal.  This tells Rails that you want an Ajax call to the server when the form is submitted, not a full page post.

**Controller changes**

You'll need to respond to formats other than HTML.  Something like this:

```
def save
  if !user_params.nil?
    @email = Email.new(user_params)
    @email.save_with_captcha
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @email, notice: 'This should not happen.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show' }
      format.js   { render action: 'show' }
    end
  end
end
```

**Javascript to insert/clear "flash" error message in your modal**

View file - show.js.erb (can be named differently but name should match action above).

```
$('#build_error').remove();
<% if @email.errors.any? %>
  var build_error = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='build_error'>";
  build_error += "The form contains <%= pluralize(@email.errors.count, 'error') %>.";
  build_error +=   "<ul id='error_explanation'>";
  <% @email.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    build_error += "<li><%= j msg %></li>";
  <% end %>
  build_error +=   "</ul>";
  build_error += "</div>";
  $(build_error).insertBefore( "#xxxxxx" );
<% else %>
  $('#email-modal').modal_success();
<% end %>
```

Basically, you'll need to clear any previous "flash" error message (the first line) and then either display the new one (you'll need to find somewhere in the DOM to attach it - see xxxxxx) or close the modal.  Pretty brute force but it works for me.

Hopefully you get the idea - I doubt any of this will work as is so you will need to understand the concept.